# File disappeared on Ubuntu 18.04 after being renamed

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ubuntu-18.04

After finishing work on a Python file, I renamed it and it disappeared form Desktop, where it was saved. The new name starts with a dot (.).

What happened to it and how can I get it back?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the name of a file or a directory starts with a dot, Linux considers it hidden. If your file was on the desktop, it’s most likely still there.

Open terminal and run:

```
cd ~/Desktop
ls -la
```

You should see your file on the list. Run:

```
mv old_filename new_filename
```

to rename it to something that does not start with a dot.